# extracting data from fully encrypted ubuntu hard drive from other ubuntu operating system

Tags: encryption, luks, solaris

I installed Ubuntu in an hard drive with encryption but there was a problem in loading opreating system. So, I'm trying to copy my data from that hard drive by connecting it with another system having Ubuntu. In disks its show the 2 drives, one is 256gb nvme and other is 537 MB Block Device. the orignal 256gb hard drive have 4 partitions in which bpool and rpool are zfs-member and partition type is solaris root. hwo can I mount this hard drive